# C++ std::async does not spawn a new thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, stdasync

C++11

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::async(std::launch::async, [](){ 
        while(true) cout << "async thread" <<endl; 
    });
    while(true) cout << "main thread" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the output should be something interleaved with `async thread` and    `main thread` since there should be 2 different threads.

But it's not.

It outputs:

```
async thread
async thread
async thread
async thread
...
```

I guess there's only one thread. Can someone tell me why it isn't spawn a new thread for `std::async`? Thanks.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async - Read the notes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change to this:

```
auto _ = std::async(std::launch::async, [](){ 
    while(true) cout << "async thread" <<endl; 
});
```

Document:

> If the std::future obtained from std::async is not moved from or bound
>   to a reference, the destructor of the std::future will block at the
>   end of the full expression until the asynchronous operation completes,
>   essentially making code such as the following synchronous:
>
> std::async(std::launch::async, []{ f(); }); // temporary's dtor waits
>   for f() std::async(std::launch::async, []{ g(); }); // does not start
>   until f() completes